# Codeigniter, multiple domains

Tags: codeigniter, dns

I am building a multi-language site with english and french. The site is made so that my default controller is /en and the french site entry controller will be at /fr.

The problem is that the french site will have a different domain, will that be a problem to point the french domain to the /fr controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be. If you have 2 domains then it's best if you "hide" the `/fr` and `/en` part from the URI (using `.htaccess`), otherwise you'll end up with `domain.com/en` and `domain.fr/fr`.

Here's an interesting article on this topic: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html

Comment: Thanks for the andwer Robert, so to make sure you mean that i can point my site.fr domain to my /fr controller though i need to make sure that to rewrite site.fr/fr to just site.fr?

What is dont get though is that in case of separated install i could point a domain to a different forlder and this folder name would not show in the address so how come it would show up in the case of a controller ?

Comment: CI routes everything to index.php. With `.htaccess` you can remove it from the URL. FR is not a folder, but a controller, thus it should be calles as `/fr`. Another way of doing it would be to create a folder called `fr`, place a copy of `index.php` in there and create a global variable (as a config setting) with the language in it.